# Regex to find non matches

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am using notepad++ and using below regex to identity the correctness of "type"

Regex:

```
<a class="web" type="([a-z]+)([0-9]+)">
```

Text which I am searching mentioned below

```
<a class="web" type="fig1">Fig 1</a>
```

With the above regex I am check correctness of both "type" and value which has been tagged (i.e. type="fig1" matching with tagged value Fig 1 or not).

Most of the cases (approx 98% will be correct) and only few cases I need to correct such as from `<a class="web" type="fig1">Fig 4</a>` to `<a class="web" type="fig4">Fig 4</a>`.

Can anybody help me by providing regex to find non-matching values as mentioned in my last para.

Comment: You could try to create regex that will contain only disallowed characters

Answer (score 2):

You can check that with notepad++:

```
search: <a class="web" type="fig(\d+)">Fig (?!\1)\d+</a>
```

And you can do a replaceAll:

```
search: (<a class="web" type="fig)(\d+)(">Fig (?!\2)(\d+)</a>)
replace: $1$4$3
```

Or you can do a blind search/replace, that replaces the attribute with the content in all cases:

```
search: (<a class="web" type="fig)\d+(">Fig (\d+))
replace: $1$3$2
```

Comment: @m.buettner: you are right, but note that you can't use a backreference before the capture group.

Comment: Sure, but why is that relevant? Also, you can never do that unless in a loop (in some flavors).

Comment: @m.buettner:Because, i have tried to do that with the capture group in the content and the backreference in the attribute!

Comment: Ah okay. Yeah, I think that would work in no flavor. Here is some more info on forward references, if you're interested: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#invalid